# Vichuploader breaks entity - Unexpected EOF

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony5

I am installing the package Vichuploader (https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle).
To make the file upload when no other inputs are changed from the entity I migrated my entity to add `updated_at` field.

After this migration my entity does not update anymore.
I can create a new entity without any problems but I have weird (non 500) errors:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30+2 seconds exceeded (terminated) in /Users/alphabetus/Documents/repos/fluid-cms/src/Controller/BlockController.php on line 181  

ERROR| SERVER issue with server callback error="unable to fetch the response from the backend: unexpected EOF"  

ERROR| SERVER POST (502) /admin/blocks/edit/706ae964-e2c1-11ea-b09a-69c7fbc1be88 host="127.0.0.1:8004" ip="::1" scheme="https"
```

My line #181 contains the following:

```
    /**
     * @return File\Null
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->image_file; // line 81
    }

    public function setImageFile(File $image_file = null): void
    {
        $this->image_file = $image_file;
        if ($image_file) {
            $this->updated_at = new \DateTime('none');
        }
    }
```

I am new to symfony. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your error message, the time it takes to process the file is too long (more the 30 seconds) so your PHP servers kills the process.
You can use [set_time_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in your `index.php` file or change the [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in php.ini.

Also, the error points to line 181 from `BlockController.php` not your entity.

If this doesn't fix your issue please supply more details/code. I've used `VichUploderBundle` quite a lot (including the `updatedAt` trigger) without any issues.

Comment: Fresh eyes deserve the cookie. Thank you.
I was trying to log something huge on my controller thats why it was dying.


Thank you!